# If X of Y conditions met formula

Tags: excel

I have a table with some columns, three of which have drop down options, with multiple conditions. I want to structure a formula in a separate cell that should indicate a value, let's say 1, if any 2 of the three conditions have been met.

I thought of building a formula using IF and OR statements, but am wondering if there is a neater way of doing this

`=IF(OR(F8="OOL", F8="OEL", F8="SIP", AND(G8="Yes")), 1, IF(OR(F8="OOL", F8="OEL", F8="SIP", AND(I8="Yes")), 1, IF(OR(G8="Yes", I8="Yes"), 1, 0)))`

To sum up, I have three conditions, any combination of 2 of the 3 should yield the value 1.

The formula above, spits out 1, even if I select just "OOL"

Comment: Why do you do an `OR`, wouldn't it be better to sum the results of the `IF`-clauses? If the sum is larger or equal than 2, it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
= ((OR(F8={"OOL","OEL","SIP"})+(G8="Yes")+(I8="Yes"))>=2)+0
```

This is a way to check every condition without needing to physically type each condition out in the formula twice.

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
=IF(OR(A1="Y", B1="Y")+OR(A1="Y", C1="Y")+OR(B1="Y", C1="Y")=2, 1, 0)
'alternate
=--(countif(A1:C1, "Y")=2)
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer. Just change to >=2

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but got stuck on the op's *'any combination of 2 of the 3'* and decided that the op could adjust if needed.

Comment: I am trying: `=IF(OR(F8="OOL", F8="OEL", F8="SIP", G8="Yes")+OR(F8="OOL", F8="OEL", F8="SIP", I8="Yes")+OR(G8="Yes", I8="Yes")=2, 1, 0)`. The result though is leading to a 1 if I just select one condition. I think the issue is that for F8, there are three options, any one that is chosen in combination with G8 or I8 can lead to 1, since the F8 options appear twice I think there is double countring

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood properly your question, but this formula will return 1 only if 2 (or 3) of your 3 requierements are met:

```
=IF(AND(H8="Yes";G8="Yes");1;IF(AND(OR(F8="OOL";F8="OEL";F8="SIP");G8="Yes");1;IF(AND(OR(F8="OOL";F8="OEL";F8="SIP");H8="Yes");1;0)))
```

If requirements are not met, then it will return 0.